# mdframed produce blank pages

Tags: mdframed, blank-page

I'm trying to compile a code like this one.

```
\documentclass[spanish, a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}
%-----Español----------
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%------------------------------------
\usepackage{blindtext}
%------------------------------------
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{framed} 

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{mdframed}
\textbf{Blablablabla}
\begin{itemize}
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Blabla blabla blabla blabla}
\blindtext

\blindtext

blablabla
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \blindtext
    \item \blindtext
    \item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\end{mdframed}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

If you compile, you'll see that the 2nd page is empty.
Something strange happens with the text length: if I change some words, everything works well.

Aparently this problem appears when you use `enumerate` or `itemize` environments.

Somebody knows why?

Thanks in advance,
Pher

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can't reproduce your result -- for me, the second page isn't empty

Comment: Same here: no blank pages when I compile the code with pdfLaTeX. This is TeX Live 2015. Are you using a different engine or distribution?

Comment: Ouch! I found that my texlive version is from 2012. But I obtained it a month ago  with the synaptic package manager. I'm a begginer in debian. I thought the synaptic package manager provides the current version. I'm trying to find out about this...

Comment: Happy ending! Finally I installed debian 8 and everything worked perfectly. Thanks, fellows!